# How can I tell if a website blocking my scraping code

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning about web scraping and I have written some code that scrapes information from [autotrader.co.uk](https://www.autotrader.co.uk/) using Python and Beautiful Soup 4. Sometimes the code will stall and then crash. The error message is related to a list that should be populated being empty.

After it crashes, I try to manually visit the website in my browser and the page never opens. If I try again later, it opens fine.

So I'm guessing that the website doesn't like me accessing it too much in a short space of time and temporarily blocks me or something like that.

My question is, is there a way I can definitively check that the website blocking my requests is the problem? Also, is there a way that a can get past this problem? Perhaps by introducing a delay between the requests?

Comment: This certainly sounds like rate-limiting. One thing to check is to have your code report the response code to your http request. They could be blocking attmepts to scrape the site, or you could be hitting a DDOS filter that doesn;t like the looks of your traffic pattern. You can use `time.sleep` to space out your requests if you think this is the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the response you get back:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/'

response=requests.get(url)

print (response)
```

**Output:**

```
<Response [200]>
```

Look at response coded [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for an idea